# problem parsing a file and then executing 2 commands in pipe

Tags: c, pipe, exec, system, system-calls

I am making a program in which I need to read from a file and execute the command in pipe. The command could be something like "ps -lu user | sort", and I should execute the first command and then the second, in different processes (using fork and exec). The problem comes when I do the exec and it doesn't work correctly.
What I have so far is the following:

```
`int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  int file = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
  int fd[2]; int pid;
  char s[8192]; 
  int nBytes = read(file, &s, 8192);  
  char* s2 =malloc(8192); char* s3 = malloc(8192);
  char* comando1[8192]; char* comando2[8192];
  s2 = strtok(s, "|"); 
  s3 = strtok(NULL, "\n"); 
  comando1[0] = strtok(s2, " ");
  int i; 
  if(s2 != NULL)
    for(i = 1; comando1[i] = strtok(NULL, " \t"); i++);
  comando2[0] = strtok(s3, " ");
  if(s3 != NULL)
    for(i = 1; comando2[i] = strtok(NULL, " \t"); i++); 
  pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0){//
    pipe(fd); 
    int pid2 = fork();
    if (pid2 > 0){
      printf("%s\n", comando1[0]);
      close(1);
       close(fd[0]); //cerramos stdout y extremo de lectura
      dup(fd[1]); close(fd[1]); //redireccionamos salida estándar a la pipe  
      execvp(comando1[0], &comando1[0]); //ejecutamos el comando 1 con salida pipe 
      perror("Error");
      write(2, "Error en el exec1", 17);
    }
    else if(pid == 0){
      close(fd[1]); close(0); //cerramos extremo de escritura y stdin
      dup(fd[0]); close(fd[0]); //redirección entrada estándar a la pipe
      printf("%s\n", comando2[0]);
      execvp(comando2[0], &comando2[0]); //ejecutamos el comando 1 con salida pipe 
      perror("Error");  
      write(2, "Error en el exec2", 17);
    }
  }

}
```

```
`
```

Which does not work as expected. For a file "file.txt" with the following command: "ps -lu user | sort -n -r", it says:

```
 sort: 
illegal option --
usage: sort [-cmu] [-o output] [-T directory] [-S mem] [-z recsz] [-dfiMnr] [-ddfiMnr] [-sdmem] [-sdm] [-z recsz
        [-dfiMnr] [-b] [-t char] [-k keydef] [+pos1 [-pos2]] files....
```

However, if I manually add the parameters keeping everything the same (change execlp to execvp and pass (execlp("ps", "ps", "-lu", "user", 0) and execlp("sort", "sort", 0); the result is as expected (but it is not correct since I am not reading from the file). what could it be due to?

Comment: I'm unsure what you need help with. You say that you've gotten the pipelining to work by manually entering the commands in the two `execlp`s - so it seems that what you actually need help with is parsing the file - yet, you don't mention that in the title. Please make a [mre] with only the part you actually need help with. Remove the other parts of the program. They are only a distraction.

Comment: I dont know where I have the error, but I am sure it is in the parse or in the exec, but have tested both (parse with printf to debugg whats in the arrays and exec by passing args manually), and cannot see the error. This is the minimal reproducible example... it cannot be more minimal and it is reproducible. In the example I parse the file and then do tje exec in pipe. Is not possible to be more minimal I think.